# Why no unbounded following in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

Why am I not able to use *unbounded following* in MySQL?

I can use *unbounded preceding* without any issue with the same query.

```
SELECT deptno,
       ENAME
       SAL,
       HIREDATE,
       last_value(HIREDATE) OVER (
           PARTITION BY deptno
           ORDER BY HIREDATE
           ROWS UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
       )
FROM emp2
ORDER BY DEPTNO, HIREDATE;
```

#### Output:

> [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near
> `FOLLWOING ) FROM emp2 ORDER BY DEPTNO, HIREDATE` at line 2

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to use the [window frame specification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html):

- Explicitly specifying the lower frame bound and implicitly using `current row` as the upper bound
- Explicitly specifying both lower and upper bounds

See the manual:

> The frame_extent value indicates the start and end points of the frame. You can specify just the start of the frame (in which case the current row is implicitly the end) or use BETWEEN to specify both frame endpoints

What you want to write is this:

```
SELECT 
  deptno, ename, sal, hiredate,
  last_value (hiredate) OVER (
    PARTITION BY deptno 
    ORDER BY hiredate 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
  )
FROM emp2
ORDER BY deptno, hiredate
```